# Splinter headless option rejected

Tags: python, python-3.x, firefox, headless-browser, splinter

I got this error while using the Browser object in splinter:

```py
>>> from splinter import Browser

>>> brow = Browser('firefox', headless=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 49, in __init__
    timeout=timeout, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headless'
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'headless'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RedEyed now, what I have to do?

Comment: @FedericoLolli What is your version of firefox?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ resolved, the problem was exactly firefox version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that headless is supported only from firefox 55 onwards.